# Sencha touch 2: Sorting / Grouping automatically fire when update data in store

Tags: listview, sorting, sencha-touch-2, store, grouping

I have a model as following:

```
Ext.define('MyProject.model.Contact', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'ID'
        },
        {
            name: 'Image'
        },
        {
            name: 'Name'
        },
        {
            name: 'IsSelected'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

I have a store use this model.This store has a group function as below:

```
        groupFn: function(item) {
            if (item.get('Name')) {
                return item.get('Name')[0].toUpperCase();
            } else {
                return ' ';
            }
        }
```

I show this store in a listview, the template of listview as below:

```
<img src="{Image}" height="45" width="45">
<span style="">{Name}</span>
<span style="float:right; padding-right: 40px;">
   <input type="checkbox" <tpl if="IsSelected === true">checked="checked"</tpl>/>
</span>
```

The list show as image below:
[image: The listview show data]

When user clicks on an item of list, I update the "IsSelected" field as below:

```
onListItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    var isSelected = record.getData().IsSelected;
    if (isSelected === true) {
        record.set("IsSelected", false);
    } else {
        record.set("IsSelected", true);
    }
}
```

After event fired, the list is automatically update. Please see below image:
[image: The listview after data updated]

All item checked is moved to the end of a group.
Are there anyone know it? Please tell me why and how to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can you run [sort](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sort) manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a sorter to your store:

```
    sorters : [{
        property : 'Name', 
        direction : 'Asc'
    }]
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://new.senchafiddle.com/#87wSV/).

Sorry...those fiddle links never work right- here's a [working example](http://api.senchafiddle.com/v3/full/87wSV/) working example.

Let me know if that doesn't work and I can get you the code I downloaded.

Good luck, Brad

Comment: Thank you so much Brad. The fiddle is working but mine is not. Could you please send me your downloaded code? Waiting for you :)